# Wondering about the mechanics of a Living Horcrux

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

I have very little experience with this series, I have only fully seen *Fantastic Beasts* and bits and pieces of the main films and never read the books, so forgive me if this is a rookie or obvious answer.

So you might be asking, why is he asking this?

Well, I was doing research for items in a game that I will probably never make in trillion years and ran into a Wikipedia  page that listed the magical items in the Potterverse. Horcruxes caught my eye as it was stated that whatever was made into one was pretty much invincible barring like a few methods of destruction. It said living things could be made into them.

Let us say you made a mayfly into one, would it not die in a day or so? Could you still smash them with a rolled up newspaper and kill it? If you made it into one before it turned into an adult, would it stay a nymph?

Just curious, as it sounds like an interesting concept.

Comment: I suspect Rowling didn't put much thought into it - her storytelling and characters are great but her worldbuilding has lots of gaps.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/is-a-living-being-a-poor-choice-for-a-horcrux

Comment: Judging from the attempts in the books/films to destroy Voldemort's various horcruxes, they'd fight back against a simple newspaper (they contained a portion of the Dark Lord's power). Transformation? No idea, JK's not written about that yet AFAIK.

Comment: I see, I mean I am not the best storyteller but this seems like it is a VERY obvious thing to explain show the readers.. @SteveIves

Comment: I don't think there's enough canonical information to answer this, although I'm willing to be wrong.

Comment: "We don't know" is a perfectly acceptable answer, not sure why this was closed as opinion based

Comment: It seems that SEs, at least the Worldbuilding one that I use 90% of that time has Closing fever, like a question I asked on there about how a species capable of decent/good flight naturally would effect the history/use of aircraft was closed for not being clear enough(I think), but for some reason not my question about if sapient cockroaches taking fall damage is reasonable. The later is a valid question, but still the first is a golden worldbuilding question. It seems the fever has spread to here as well. I mean, most/many of the answers here opinion based? I hope this fever breaks soon. @fez

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm just a random user with no authority in any way) From my perspective, Sci-Fi Stack Exchange is quite reasonable when it comes to closing questions. Still, when I read your question, my first impression was: "hmm... that's almost on the edge of the hypothetical and 'what if' stuffs". In the end, I decided not to vote to close, because it's not so far off either. If you knew the universe better, you might have asked whether or not the _known living horcrux_ could get old and pass away like anyone else. It _might_ have been less hypothetical.

Comment: As a bonus: if I wanted to nitpick (like, badly), the title and some wordings of the post might not help either. Stuffs like "Let us say you made a mayfly into one" and "Just curious, as it sounds like an interesting concept" may make it look like you are looking for opinion rather than anything that is backed up by source. Then again, I'm not an authoritative figure, so you should take what I say with a grain of salt (or a spoonful, actually).

Comment: The mayfly one was just an example for people to use to explain the workings of living horcruxses. Plus, I mean a bit of opinion is needed in this type of SE anyway, imo, same for Worldbuilding SE. @Clockwork

Comment: In trying to think of an edit to make this question appear less opinion based I found  [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11627), which looks to me almost exactly what you're asking, just in a more succinct way

Comment: So, the answer is it is unknown if they are nigh-immortals, for now at least, I guess. Still a weird reason to close it, but at least I got my answer. @fez

Comment: Also, thanks for the link. @fez

Comment: The question is a little bit vague, but honestly, why do we need to shut down every question that needs a little bit of clarification? Close votes seem to be the go-to method for removing questions that don't perfectly fit this site's standards.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256279/how-was-the-horcrux-in-nagini-destroyed-when-only-a-few-specific-things-can-des/256291#256291